# I have hard time with debugging long compile time and multiple user input requirement

Tags: c++

I am in need of desperate help because I cannot figure out why and what am I doing wrong. I am trying to ask the user multiple questions about length conversion. I encounter a problem where only the first question is asked, and the next one will not have chance to be asked. I have tried two versions, but they were both flawed.

[Sample output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V1yT.jpg)

```
Sisestage pikkus meetrides:
500
Sisestage uue uhiku kood (alj, ver, kyn, toll, jalg, jard, lii):
Sisestasite  vale vaartuse:500 void vale uhiku:
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string> 
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    float P;              /* Pikkus meetrites  */ /*Length P in metres*/
    string U;             /* M66du:hik*/ /* Unit of measure*/

    float ALJ;  
    float VER; 
    float KYN; 
    float TOLL; 
    float JALG; 
    float JARD; 
    float LII; 

    do
    { 
        cout<<"Sisestage pikkus meetrides: \n";  /*Ku:sin kasutajalt pikkust P*/ /* Asking       user for the length P in metres*/
        cin>>P; 
        if (P > 0)  
            cout<<"Sisestage uue uhiku kood (alj, ver, kyn, toll, jalg, jard, lii): \n"; /* Ku:sin         kasutajalt u:hiku koodi U*/ /* Asking user for the length U in metres*/
        getline(cin, U);
    } while (P > 0);     
    cout << "Sisestasite  vale vaartuse:"<<P<< endl; /*Veateade*/   
    ALJ = P / 5572;  
    VER = P / 1066.781; 
    KYN = P / 0.53; 
    TOLL = P / 0.0254; 
    JALG = P / 0.3048; 
    JARD = P / 0.9144; 
    LII = P / 500;


    if( U == "alj")
    { 
        cout<< setprecision(2)<<fixed<< P <<"m = "<< ALJ << U <<"." ;
    } 
    else if( U == "ver")
    {
        cout<< setprecision(2) << fixed << P <<" m ="<< VER << U <<".";
    }
    else if( U == "kyn") 
    {
        cout<< setprecision(2) << fixed << P <<" m ="<< KYN << U <<".";
    } 
    else if( U == "toll") 
    {
        cout<< setprecision(2) << fixed << P <<" m ="<< TOLL << U <<"."; 
    } 
    else if( U == "jalg")
    {
        cout<< setprecision(2) << fixed << P<<" m ="<< JALG << U <<".";
    } 
    else if( U == "jard")
    {
        cout<< setprecision(2) << fixed << P <<" m ="<< JARD << U <<".";
    } 
    else if( U == "lii")
    {
        cout<< setprecision(2) << fixed << P <<" m ="<< LII << U <<".";
    }


    getchar(); 
    getchar();

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question title at all.

Comment: "I have a hard time debugging my program that requires multiple instances of user input. This is partially because of a long compile time".

Comment: @Kevin: Indeed, but the above code should take no time at all to compile!

Comment: Are you getting a compile time error at the 2nd user input? Try setting a breakpoint after here:  cout<<"Sisestage pikkus meetrides: \n";  /*Ku:sin kasutajalt pikkust P*/ /* Asking       user for the length P in metres*/
        cin>>P;

Comment: it is hard enough to debug code. in a foreign language even more. Maybe you could at least rename your variables to english names so we know what they are supposed to do..

Answer (score 0):

It's kind'a hard to tell what's going on with this indentation but did you mean to include the getline in the if() block? Maybe you're missing {}

```
 if (P > 0)  
 cout<<"Sisestage uue uhiku kood (alj, ver, kyn, toll, jalg, jard, lii): \n"; /* Ku:sin         kasutajalt u:hiku koodi U*/ /* Asking user for the length U in metres*/
 getline(cin, U);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You dont have any opening `{` and closing `}` on the validation line:

```
if (P > 0)  
 cout<<"Sisestage uue uhiku kood (alj, ver, kyn, toll, jalg, jard, lii): \n"; /* Ku:sin         kasutajalt u:hiku koodi U*/ /* Asking user for the length U in metres*/
 getline(cin, U);
```

2.Fix your indentation as it makes errors like this easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to mix `operator<<` with `std::getline`. The former leaves the end-of-line character in the input stream, which confuses the latter.

After your call to `operator<<`, you must consume the remainder of that line. Here are two ways:

```
 // throw away rest of line
 std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

or

```
 std::string temp;
 std::getline(cin, temp); // throw away rest of line
```

Try this:

```
do
{ 
    cout<<"Sisestage pikkus meetrides: \n";  /*Ku:sin kasutajalt pikkust P*/ /* Asking       user for the length P in metres*/
    cin>>P;
    std::getline(cin, U); // throw away rest of line
    if (P > 0)  
        cout<<"Sisestage uue uhiku kood (alj, ver, kyn, toll, jalg, jard, lii): \n"; /* Ku:sin         kasutajalt u:hiku koodi U*/ /* Asking user for the length U in metres*/
    getline(cin, U); // Start on fresh line
} while (P > 0);
```

As others pointed out, you may have a logic flaw in `if(P>0)` code, but that is unrelated to your question.

Comment: Tried it, it goes on endless circle where I enter value higher than 500 and it still ignores the second input

Comment: Yes, it goes in an endless circle with any value higher than 0. That's what you coded. Only negative numbers cause the system to exit. If you mean for postive numbers to complete the input, try `while (P <= 0)`